# ANT problem with jar file

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am having a problem producing a working jar file. I would like to end up with a jar file that can run itself by using the command java -jar myjar.jar

So far I have

```
<project default="jar" name="Create Runnable Jar fecrudbreset">
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="./build"/>
    <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="./lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="./bin"/>
    <jar destfile="./bin/fecrudbreset.jar" >
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="FecruDBreset"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/> 
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="./build"/>
        <zipfileset dir="./lib" includes="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

The compile works however when I try to run the app I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource
    at FecruDBreset.main(Unknown Source)
```

update:
The main class I have uses the default package. The class is found and starts to run but fails when it cant locate the sql driver it seems. I guess I dont understand why it cant find it.

Here is how the main class is defined:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class FecruDBreset
{

/*
 * Used to reset / nuke fecru database
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
```

Also if I unzip the jar file that is produced the contents look like this:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
FecruDBreset.class
sqljdbc4.jar
```

Update 2: My source tree looks like this:

```
|-- bin
|   `-- fecrudbreset.jar
|-- build
|   `-- FecruDBreset.class
|-- build.xml
|-- lib
|   `-- sqljdbc4.jar
|-- readme.txt
`-- src
    `-- FecruDBreset.java
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks much in advance.
Chad

Comment: How do you try to run the application ?

Comment: when you run it you need to have the sqljdbc4.jar in classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @chadneal: Also if I unzip the jar file that is produced the contents look like this:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
FecruDBreset.class
sqljdbc4.jar
```

The main Jar cannot *contain* the `sqljdbc4.jar`.  Instead, a reference to that Jar should be added to the class-path in the manifest.

Comment: Ah I see. So I copied the sql driver jar file to the same directory as my jar file and it worked just fine. So does that mean I need to use some type of jarinjarloader to have the driver in my jar file?

Comment: @chadneal: "does that mean I need to use some type of jarinjarloader to have the driver in my jar file?"  I'm not familiar with those, though I've heard much about 'fatjar'.  But then, building with Ant makes it simple to create a single Jar.  Just extract the resources from each dependent Jar, then add those resources to the final 'main' Jar.  Either that or deploy the lot using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (if it has a GUI).

Answer (score 1):

Like you did in your ant file you need to add in your classpath the sqlserver jdbc driver. 
Otherwise java won't find it.

To do that you need to add the dependency jar file in the manifest of myjar.jar

You should be able to do it with the jar command of ant by passing a manifest.txt file that contains something like:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: sqljdbc4.jar (update the path if necessary)
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

See
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: classpath is ignored when running with the -jar option.

Comment: java -cp fecrudbreset.jar/sqljdbc4.jar -jar fecrudbreset.jar failed with: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fecrudbreset/jar

Comment: Edwin is right. I updated the answer. You need to add the dependency sqljdbc4.jar in the jar file.

Comment: The sqljdbc4.jar file is in the jar file and it still isnt able to find it.

Comment: it was not in the jar but in the manifest of the jar. My comment wasn't clear but my response was :-).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick guess. It looks like it can't find your class com.microsoft.sqlserver/*

Where is the jar that contain this located? Your default classpath is just ".", but it looks like you put sqljdbc4.jar in lib directory inside your jarfile.

You can modify Class-Path to include ./lib, or you can move sqljdbc4.jar jar to the root of the jarfile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the classpath entry.

You probably want to include you sql-driver directy in the class folder "fatjar" or "uberjar": http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

This will create a single jarfile, which can be executed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your main class FecruDBreset depends on com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

You should have microsoft sql driver in class path.

so you should run your jar using following command

java -jar myjar.jar -classpath {path_to_microsoft_jdbc_driver}

Comment: To quote an earlier comment (but louder this time) **"classpath is ignored when running with the -jar option."**